# Ending an array without knowing how many elements will be filled

Tags: c

I am reading in a very large CSV file and I have allocated more than enough space for all the numbers to fit in the array.  However I have no idea where to even start with figuring out how many spaces are actually used.

It is far to large to just count but I need to know the number so that I can insert an '\0' at the end.  Also so that I know how long to run some loops.

How would you go about determining the end of real data in a array?

I am working in C language.

This is how I am reading the data in:

```
for(i = 0 ; i < 10000 ; i++){
fscanf(fp,"%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,\n]",&column_1[i],&column_2[i],&column_3[i],&column_4[i],&column_5[i],&column_6[i],&column_7[i]);
```

}

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, post sample input, expected output, and observed output.

Comment: The end of the data is when you reach the end of file, and the you save the value of `i` as your number of records read.

Comment: You're reading from a file, so you know when you encounter `EOF`; you need a sentinel value in your array marking the end.

Comment: @FiddlingBits: It seems to be parsed data from a CSV. Not sure what OP actually wants; as given the question is too broad.

Comment: Why are you not checking the return of `fscanf`? It returns a value (the number of successfully matched conversions), that can be quite helpful in letting you know how many successful reads you have had... Then a counter keeping track of those will go a long way to solving your issue. e.g. `i=0; while (fscanf (...) == 7) i++;`

Answer (score 0):

Of course.  It was so obvious.  Just use a counter variable.  Thanks for the help!

```
while(!feof(fp)){
  //  if(i%)
fscanf(fp,"%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,\n]",&column_1[i],&column_2[i],&column_3[i],&column_4[i],&column_5[i],&column_6[i],&column_7[i]);
i++;
}
numberEntries = i;
```